# lambda function call to subprocess launching multiple copies of one executable

Tags: python, lambda, subprocess

I get launching of one executable multiple time, except when writing out the files first time.

```
""" Running hexlified codes from codefiles module prepared previously """

import tempfile
import subprocess
import os

import codefiles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = os.path.join(os.curdir, 'Tools')
    if not os.path.exists(p):
        os.makedirs(p)

    for fn, c in codefiles.exes:
        fnp = os.path.join(os.curdir, 'Tools', fn)
        if not os.path.exists(fnp):
            # for some reason hexlified code is sometimes odd length and one nibble
            if len(c) & 1:
                c += '0'
            c = c.decode('hex')
            with open(fnp, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(c)
        print fnp
        # this following line does not launch the second exe, but previous exe if exes existed
        # but first exe twice
        threading.Thread(target=lambda:subprocess.call([fnp])).start()
```

Here screenshot (after moving the windows from over each other) after start. notepad.exe showing in print but two puttys started.
[image]

Comment: note: `subprocess.Popen(fnp)` returns as soon as the child process is started -- it does not wait for it to finish i.e., you don't need `Thread()` here.

Comment: Thank you for information J.F. Sebastian!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fnp` may be changed by the time your `lambda` executes -- you have a race condition here, so, no surprise if the amount of I/O performed in the meantime can hide or show the race condition, since I/O slows things down.

To avoid the race condition, change your `lambda:` to `lambda fnp=fnp:` to bind the `fnp` value at the point of **creation** of the `lambda` rather than at the later time when it **executes**.

Comment: Thank you, sensei! I hope to remember this usage in other similar situations in future.